# what is zsh and bash in linux/ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu

I was installing laravel and there was an error,so i was trying to fix it and i get  [solution on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48678950/7294656)

but here  what is zsh and bash??

Comment: BASH=Bourne Again SHell; I learnt this at uni in the 80s, being a superset of (unix) SHell from the 1970s.  Bash is default in GNU (and thus GNU/Linux), OSX (apple) etc.  CSh/ZSh/KSh/.. are just alternatives with different strengths & weaknesses.  If you want a shell.script to run in everything, limit yourself to 1970's Sh (shell).  If you want better - there is a wonderful thing called a search engine - try it.  note:  this is all from my bad memory as I'm not inclined to check..  I'd not trust it for school homework :)

Comment: Shell's are the CLI or command line interfaces ... fancy names for where we put in commands understood by our computer hardware. They are very precise so ideal for machines, but the commands are usually seen as cryptic by humans (esp. the non-technical of us).  Shell's are more powerful CLIs that usually have some sort of coding capacity allowing script programming....

Answer (score 0):

zsh and bash are command interrupters. The command line interface. Also a very powerful way to setup and maintain your linux installation.

Comment: so what is difference in zsh and bash

Comment: Bash comes on just about all Linux flavors where zsh does not. most commands will work on both. Recommendation? use bash (the Bourne again shell.) it works on 99.9% of all linuxes and is dead easy to learn and implement.

Comment: thank Bunyip, now i am reading these technical linux terms,

Comment: Glad I could help.